# Call function from GridView source html

Tags: c#, asp.net, namespaces

Here's my GridView HTML:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPortfolioImages" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ldsPortfolioImages">
    <Columns>          
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image" SortExpression="Filename">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img src='<%# Portfolio.GetImageURL(Eval("Thumbnail").ToString()) %>' alt='<%# Eval("Thumbnail") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I'm get the following error where I'm trying to call Portfolio.GetImageURL():

**The name 'Portfolio' does not exist in the current context**

I've seen functions called like this before, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your aspx page you need to include the namespace so the compiler knows about your Portfolio object which I am assuming is a static class with a static function (if not you will need to instantiate your `Portfolio` object  before using it).  Here is the snippet you will need to add after the `<@ Page` at the top of your aspx file.  Replace the string with the correct namespace of course.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="YourApps.Namespace.Where.PorfolioIs" %>
```

The error is occuring because it has no idea what `Portfolio` is.  It's just like if you tried to reference it in your codebehind (.cs file) without a `using` statement including the namespace where you `Portfolio` class exists.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was forgetting to import the correct namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Portfolio is a valid object, have you provided a reference to its namespace via the using statement? Also check to make sure GetImageURL() a static function.  You may want to simply place a mock protected static string GetImageURL() function in the code-behind of your GridView. You might be able to determine is root cause through trial and error.